# error using moment.js with serverless-bundle

Tags: momentjs, serverless

how can I add moment.js locale file to serverless bundle?

Thanks for any help :)

I tried the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:AnomalyInnovations/serverless-nodejs-starter.git
cd serverless-nodejs-starter
npm i moment
```

then in file handler.js add

```
import moment from "moment";
```

and update hello with just call to `moment();` (to avoid lint error)

when running local run:

```
serverless invoke local --function hello
```

the error received:
`Error: Cannot find module './locale'`

Comment: Which version of moment did you install? (You can check in your `package.json` file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the latest version of `momentjs` as you can see in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5484). You can try the following:

1. `npm install --save moment@2.24.0`
2. Add a resolutions block in your `package.json` file as such:

```
"resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.24.0"
}
```